# Is the total space of this vector bundle embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be the Moebius vector bundle over $S^1$.

Is it possible to embedd the total space of $M\oplus (S^1\times \mathbb{R^1})$ over $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I suppose this isn't possible but I don't know an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, since the Whitney sum would be a nonorientable $3$-manifold, which cannot be embedded in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: What's the reason that a nonorientable $3$-manifold cannot be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: An orientation reversing path in $M$ would also reverse orientation of the ambient space.

Comment: I'm using that an $n$-dimensional manifold embedded in an $n$-dimensional manifold sits as an open subset, which follows from "invariance of dimension."

Comment: Slightly differently: If there existed an embedding, the image would have to be open by invariance of domain, and open subsets of $\mathbb R^3$ are orientable.

Comment: There you go :D

Comment: Invariance of domain, that's what I meant!